# Query value from next month not returning any value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I am using this to query next months value:

```php
if($stmt = $link->prepare("
  SELECT SUM(prov) as sum
  FROM tbl
  WHERE MONTH(transfer) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())+1
    AND YEAR(transfer) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
")) {
```

The issue is that it does not give me value from January 2021. I have tried the below code, but still no value is returned:

```php
if($stmt = $link->prepare("
  SELECT SUM(prov) as sum
  FROM tbl
  WHERE MONTH(transfer) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())+1
    AND YEAR(transfer) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+1
")) {
```

Example of transfer value: `2021-01-01`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done! phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You can easily understand what is the issue if you completely remove your `WHERE` clause and put all that calculations in `SELECT` list. This way you can observe calculated values and identify, how they should influence the output. Then you'll find that `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())+1` returns 13, so no such month exists. Also `month = month + 1 and year = year + 1` is effectively not hte next month, it is the next month of the next year, except Decembers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date/datetime functions:

```
SELECT SUM(prov) as sum
FROM tbl
WHERE transfer >= DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), 1 ) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND
      transfer < DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), 1 ) + INTERVAL 2 MONTH;
```

This query is formulated so it can use an index on `transfer`.